# code using the same packages of tikzcd works on one project but not other

Tags: packages, environments, commutative-diagrams

I'm using the package `\usepackage{tikz-cd}`. Note that this code works good:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
& D \arrow[d,"f"] \arrow[dl, dashrightarrow, "F"'] \\
M \arrow[r,"\phi"] & N
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

But I'm working in another project, also in `\documentclass{amsart}` with the same package. But when I put the same code between the `tikzcd` there's a compile error and it says:

```
Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.309 \end{tikzcd}
```

But I'm writing the same code that already worked on the other project ...

**EDIT**: I added `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` and then switched the syntax. I wrote this example (this should work because it's from a LaTeX tutorial of `tikzcd`):

```
\begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow{d} \arrow{r}[near start]{\phi}[near end]{\psi}
& B \arrow[red]{d}{\xi} \\
C \arrow[red]{r}[blue]{\eta}
& D
\end{tikzcd}
```

And now this is the new error:

```
Package tikz-cd Error: Diagrams cannot be nested.

See the tikz-cd package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
...
l.304 I think the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in cell 1-1.
\errmessage ...currentrow -\tikzcd@currentcolumn }
```

Comment: Are you using babel in the other project? Then the  " might be active (danish does that for example). If your installation is up to date then `\usetikzlibrary{babel} ` might help. I tend to not use the "..." feature in tikz for the same reason

Comment: Did not work =(

Comment: Then switch to the other syntax, adding labels as `\arrow[d]{f} `, note also the build in shortcuts.

Comment: In that syntax how can I use the dashrightarrow and swap?

Comment: It is just the label text that goes into braces, the rest is added as you already does.

Comment: This is a nightmare... I did what you said and now this occurs =(

Package tikz-cd Error: Diagrams cannot be nested.

See the tikz-cd package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help
...
l.304 I think the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in cell 1-1.
\errmessage ...currentrow -\tikzcd@currentcolumn }

Comment: Please add the example you are doing right now to your post

Comment: \begin{tikzcd}
A \arrow{d} \arrow{r}[near start]{\phi}[near end]{\psi}
& B \arrow[red]{d}{\xi} \\
C \arrow[red]{r}[blue]{\eta}
& D
\end{tikzcd}

I took this from a pdf that explains how to use tikzcd

Comment: If you want I can send you my tex, is very short

Comment: Update the question, please don't post long code in a comnent

Comment: Ah, yes, it gas to be written like that. My bad. Also is your latex fully updated

Comment: I'm writing in overleaf therefore it's fully updated =(

Comment: Don't be so sure on that. It would make sense for them to be behind in their updates.

Comment: But in other project on the same page the code already worked, that's the problem <.<

Comment: Please update the sniplet to also include preamble, thus making the sniplet in to something that ought to be compilable without having to add anything

Answer (score 1):

This compiles just fine on my TeX Live 2015

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzcd}
        & D \arrow[d,"f"] \arrow[dl, dashrightarrow, "F"'] \\
        M \arrow[r,"\phi"] & N
    \end{tikzcd}

    \begin{tikzcd}
        A \arrow{d} \arrow{r}[near start]{\phi}[near end]{\psi}
        & B \arrow[red]{d}{\xi} \\
        C \arrow[red]{r}[blue]{\eta}
        & D
    \end{tikzcd}


\end{document}
```